# Publishing a .Net Core 6 Windows Application Will Not Run

Tags: .net-core

I thought the idea of .Net Core was that I did not have to install a Run-Time, it was included in the published code. However, when I run my App nothing happens. The Application Event Log says..."Message: You must install .NET to run this application." When I look for .NET Core Runtimes, I only find SDK's. Where are the run-times? What is the published "Runtimes" folder for?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core is just a smaller runtime, mostly split into separate libraries, but it certainly DOES require a runtime, just like normal .NET programs. At build time you could bundle it in the exe or you can depend on an external installed library, but ultimately it's still a dependency, much like with the real .NET Framework.

You can find the runtimes in the Microsoft website. Ror example, here is the .NET Core 6 runtimes download webpage, containing the SDKs, ASP libraries and the standalone runtime.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/es-es/download/dotnet/6.0